# Advanced alias in zsh shell

Tags: zsh, arch-linux, bash-alias

I'm using the zsh shell on ArchLinux and I want to know if there's an easy way to make "advanced" aliases.

Normal aliases work just fine. However I can't find a way to create an alias for a substitution like:

```
git clone git@home:some-repo.git
```

to

```
git clone git@192.168.2.2:repositories/some-repo.git
```

Is there any simple way at all to do this directly in zsh with alias (or something similar)? Of course it should be generic so I don't need and alias for every git action on every repository.

Thanks in advande!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case, you can do it through git rather than through zsh. Add the following to your `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[url "git@192.168.2.2:repositories/"]
    insteadOf = "home:"
```

Now `git clone home:some-repo.git` (and other git commands) will use the correct repo.

In the more general case, if you want to do a command substitution that's more advanced than what an alias allows, look at [shell functions](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_4.html).